# First tick on min and last tick on max

Tags: highcharts

I would like the ticks on my chart for the Y axis to start on the minimum value of the dataset and end on the maximum value.

I've been using this dataset to test:

```
chartData = [30, 20, 100, 130, 40, 90];
```

I've tried to calculate the max and min of the set and use the `setExtremes()` method but with no success. When I do that, the the first tick is 0 and the last one is 240. When I don't use `setExtremes()`, the first tick is 0 and the last one is 160, so `setExtremes()` actually makes it worse. I read in the documentation that if `endOnTick` and `startOnTick` are set to `true`, the minimum and maximum are rounded off to the nearest tick, but if I set them to `false`, I'm only getting 1 tick and it's at 100.

Is there any way to achieve this? I'm not sure if it matters, but my charts are very small:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default Highcharts launches its own algorithms to find optimal values for ticks. `setExtremes` only takes care of setting minimum and maximum values visible on the plot - it doesn't guarantee that ticks will fall on these values.

`tickPositions` forces Highcharts to put ticks on given positions:

```
tickPositions: [Math.min(...data), Math.max(...data)]
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/mwe1mgrg/

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositions

Comment: Thanks! `tickPositions` didn't work for me, but this did: 

  `tickPositioner: function(){
            return [this.dataMin, this.dataMax];
        },`

Answer (score 0):

Hey Guys it would help you to solve an issue ;) (Angular 5)

I think you can pass whatever you want inside update function to update your axis.

```
    this.chart.ref.xAxis[0].update({tickPositions: [1,2,3,4,5]}, true);
```

Enjoy. Maks Yaremenko